# DataInputStream readert blocks

Tags: java, sockets

I'm reading and writing bytes on an open socket. This is my code.

```
@Test
public void testSingleRequest() throws IOException {
    Server server = new Server(9000, 100);
    new Thread(server).start();
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    String payload = "a";
    byte[] load = buildPushPayload(payload);
    out.write(load);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
    for (int i = 0; i <128 ; i++) {
        int read = in.read(buffer, 0, 128);
    }
    out.close();
    server.stop();
    assertEquals(0, buffer[0]);
```

Since I'm reading a fixed length, I believe the for loop shouldn't block, but it still does. How do I get the loop to unblock?

Comment: even though this whole test looks weird but please use separate threads for client and server operations and do out.flush()/close() right after sending just for checking.

Comment: If I do out.close() before reading then the InputStream is a null pointer. The server though is closing the out soon after writing.

Comment: How does the code at the other end know how many bytes you're sending? Maybe it is awaiting and hasn't even started sending a response yet. Difficult to know, since we don't know what that code is doing.

Comment: @Andreas so how do I do a fixed length read of 128 bytes on both end?

Comment: Well, if you want to do a fixed-length read of 128 bytes, you should start by not trying to read 128 bytes 128 times, because that is an attempt to read 128 * 128 = 16384 bytes.

Comment: @Andreas can you please help me with some code here.

Comment: i would recommend using NIO with `ByteBuffer`s and here's your code just as is and it does what you wanted i guess the reading lengths you can do by yourself with `while` https://pastebin.com/Q8vEH6rZ

Comment: @SergeyBenner this is not what I'm trying to do. The test spins up a server and a client, the client writes to the socket and the server sends a response which the client reads.

Comment: @Melissa Stewart this is exactly what the code does which I pasted the URL for

Comment: How do you know that it's the client that's in error, and not the server? Anyway, try closing `out` before you begin reading `in`.